# Give examples of functions $f$ such that $f$ is differentiable at $0$, but $f'(x)$ is not continuous at $0$

Tags: derivatives

**1. Give examples of functions $f$ such that $f$ is differentiable at $0$, but $f'(x)$ is not continuous at $0$**

Is $x\sin\frac{1}{x}$ one of the example? I'm not sure about this one

**2. Give examples of functions $f$ such that $f$ is only continuous at the irrationals in $(0,1)$**

I don't quite understand this question. How's that possible for a function to        be continuous without rational numbers?

Comment: For 2. the textbook example is [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae's_function)

Comment: 1. No that's not an example. Write down the definition of the derivative at $0.$

Comment: These are two completely unrelated questions, so they should not appear together.

Comment: Still can't get why Thomae's function satisfy question 2. Can anyone give more detailed explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint for 1: $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$ for $x\ne0$, $f(0)=0$.

Comment: In this case $f'(x)=0$, but how to show that it's continuous at 0

Comment: @user289293 It's *not* continuous at $0$, as you asked for.

Comment: If I do it correctly, $f'(x)= 2xsin\frac{1}{x}+x^2cos(\frac{1}{x})(-1)\frac{1}{x^2}$ how to show that $lim_{x\to_0}f'(x)=f'(0)$

Comment: @user289293 Correct, for $x\ne0$, it can be simplified to $f'(x)=2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x)$; also right is $f'(0)=0$. Does there exist $\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)$? Note that you are requested to find that the derivative is ***not*** continuous at $0$.

Comment: $lim_{x_\to 0}f'(x)=lim_{x_\to 0}2xsin\frac{1}{x}-lim_{x_\to0}cos\frac{1}{x}$ but $ lim_{x_\to0}cos\frac{1}{x}$does not exist

Comment: Oh...you are right! Why am I trying to prove it is continuous?